# angular or html how to display a template by a condition

Tags: html, angular

I am new to angular and html - this should be an easy question but I could not find the answer
I have a table and a Save button that once the user is clicking it the values in the table needs to be disabled - i am using primeNg table with the following code

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-category let-index="rowIndex">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="category">
      <div *ngIf="isEditable  then editTemplate  else saveTemplate">
          <td pEditableColumn #editTemplate>
          <p-cellEditor>
            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
              <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="category.categoryName">
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
              {{category.categoryName}}
            </ng-template>
          </p-cellEditor>
        </td>
          <td #saveTemplate>{{category.categoryName}}</td>
      </div>

      <!-- <td>{{category.categoryName}}</td> -->
      <td>{{category.effectiveDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="category.questions.length else changeNullToZero">
        {{category.questions.length}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" label="Remove" icon="pi pi-check" 
                (click)="confirmDeleteCategory(categoriesList[index])"
          pButton></button>
      </td>
      <ng-template #changeNullToZero>
        <td>0</td>
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I want that once the Save button is clicked the values will be disabled
I tried to give an alias to the 2 templates ( editTemplate  and saveTemplate )   and to check the value of the isEditable - but i am doing some thing wrong ...
note that when I remove the div with the ngIf and just put the EditTample part

```
<div *ngIf="isEditable ; then editTemplate ; else saveTemplate">
```

the fields are editable and if i just put the

```
<td>{{category.categoryName}}</td>
```

the field is not editable meaning just the if part is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Wrap your `td` content within `ng-template`
> 2. Replace `div` by `ng-container` in tr section.

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-category let-index="rowIndex">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="category">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="isEditable ? editTemplate : saveTemplate ; context: {category : category}">
    
        </ng-container>
    
    <!-- <td>{{category.categoryName}}</td> -->
    <td>{{category.effectiveDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
    <td *ngIf="category.questions.length else changeNullToZero ">{{category.questions.length}}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" label="Remove" icon="pi pi-check" (click)="confirmDeleteCategory(categoriesList[index])"
                pButton></button>
    </td>
    <ng-template #changeNullToZero>
        <td>0</td>
    </ng-template>
    </tr>
    </ng-template>
    
    <ng-template  #editTemplate let-category="category"> 
        <td pEditableColumn>
        <p-cellEditor>
            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="category.categoryName">
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                {{category.categoryName}}
            </ng-template>
        </p-cellEditor>
    </td>
    </ng-template>
    
    <ng-template  #editTemplate let-category="category"> 
        <td #saveTemplate>{{category.categoryName}}</td>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: thank you But  it is not working - now I don't see the column valus at all ( I tried to play with this but still failing )

Comment: I just moved the ng-template outside and defined the context for template. Please check answer if it helps now. Here is the sample example for ref  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-else-fku8pb